# Materialize CSS sideNav closeOnClick not working

Tags: jquery, materialize

I am using Materialize css on a one page site.

I can not get the sideNav to close when the links in the sideNav are clicked.  I am fairly new to jquery so I must be missing something

I am initialising the sidenav with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
          menuWidth: 300, // Default is 300
          edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
          closeOnClick: true, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
          draggable: true // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
        }
      );

});
```

this is my html

```
            <ul class="side-nav" id="slide-out">
            <li><a class="welcome waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#welcome">Welcome</a></li>
            <li><a class="about waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#about">About </a></li>
            <li><a class="where waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#where">Where we work</a></li>
            <li><a class="acheivements waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#acheivements">2016 Acheivements</a></li>
            <li><a class="fundraising waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#fundraising">2016 fundraising</a></li>
            <li><a class="potential waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#case-studies">Case studies</a></li>
            <li><a class="financial waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#financial-highlights">highlights</a></li>
            <li><a class="outlook waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#outlook">Outlook </a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
```

I am referencing the init.js file in my index.html
All the other materialize things are working
I have even gone into the main file and changed the default to closeOnClick: true  but it still won't close on click.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have spent days on this now.....

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can edit your question and use the `add Javascript / html / css snippet` option, add any dependencies and make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

To make your example work, I added a missing: `<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">` at the beginning of your list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
    menuWidth: 300, // Default is 300
    edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
    closeOnClick: true, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    draggable: true // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
  <li><a class="welcome waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#welcome">Welcome</a></li>
  <li><a class="about waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#about">About </a></li>
  <li><a class="where waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#where">Where we work</a></li>
  <li><a class="acheivements waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#acheivements">2016 Acheivements</a></li>
  <li><a class="fundraising waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#fundraising">2016 fundraising</a></li>
  <li><a class="potential waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#case-studies">Case studies</a></li>
  <li><a class="financial waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#financial-highlights">highlights</a></li>
  <li><a class="outlook waves-effect waves-am-red" href="#outlook">Outlook </a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse">
  <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</a>
```

Comment: that was already there - it's my first time using it and for some reason that first line didn't get included in the code section. (updated now)

Weird thing is... The other options such as the menu alignment work and i can change them but the closeonclick is not working.

Comment: Actually i have some javascript that is making the anchors scroll to the correct position that was causing the closeOnClick not to work.
Seeing your working demo made me realise the problem must be elsewhere thanks!!!!